# Do separate calls to mmap with MAP_SHARED use the same area of shared memory?

Tags: linux, posix

I'm trying to understand the way MAP_SHARED affects mmap.

The manual says:

> **MAP_SHARED** Share this mapping. Updates to the mapping are visible to other processes mapping the same region, and (in the case of file-backed mappings) are carried through to the underlying file. (To precisely control when updates are carried through to the underlying file requires the use of msync(2).)

It's unclear to me whether changes are carried across from one process to another via the underlying object (file) if so that would mean `msync ()` is needed to ensure other processes can see the change.

Alternatively, are the files mapped into shared memory which is reused by other calls to `mmap ()` on the same region of a file?

If so, all changes would immediately be available to other processes.

Comment: The changes would be visible to other processes "immediately" and in-memory, subject to the usual rules on cache coherence. No round trip to disk required.

Comment: The documentation seems clear to me. Making changes visible to other processes and propogating them to the file are separate, indepentent results.

Comment: What about truncations and writes that extend the length of the file from a second/other process? How do these propagate back into the original process address space, if those pages were already loaded from a prior read. That is it seems to imply that the memory could be volatile between reads.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai It's better to ask new questions than commenting on old ones.  Truncating down an `mmap`'d  area of a file out of existence is undefined by POSIX.  Under linux a SIGBUS error should be thrown when you try to access the memory http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html.  Extending a file does not affect existing data in the file.  You always `mmap` a specific region, what happens outside that region shouldn't matter.  To be clear, if you `mmap` a region at the end of the file, extending the file happens outside of your mapping.